# Unit test with mockK - flatMap

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, rx-java, mockk

I'm new in Unit Testing, I can't understand how to test this kind of method with kotlin, using MockK:

```kotlin
override fun register(firebaseId: String, uniqueId: String): Completable {
    return Observable.just(0).observeOn(schedulerProvider.io()).flatMap {
        
        val requestRegisterPushes = registerBuilder.build(firebaseId, uniqueId)
        apiServiceFactory.build()
            .registerPushes(requestRegisterPushes)
            .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
            .observeOn(schedulerProvider.ui())

    }.flatMapCompletable { 
        Completable.complete() 
    }
}
```

This is my code for the test, the test was a success but the condition coverage does not increase.

```kotlin
@Test
fun `register_Test()`() {

    val requestRegisterPushes = mockk<RequestRegisterPushes>(relaxed = true)
    every { registerBuilder.build(any(), any(), any(), any()) } returns requestRegisterPushes
    every { apiServiceFactory.build().register(requestRegisterPushes) } returns Observable.just(SimpleResponse())


    val resp = userRepository.register("x7gbyb68837g78s", "XXX-XXX-XXX")
}
```

I would really appreciate it if you could help me a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you don't have any coverage because code inside `flatmap` and `flatMapCompletable` operator was not executed.

You need to **subscribe** to `Observable` to make it emmit elements in you case it will emmit 0 only when you **subscribe** for it. That's how RxJava works. Something like this:

```
val subscriber = TestSubscriber<>();

val resp = userRepository.register("x7gbyb68837g78s", "XXX-XXX-XXX").subscribe(subscriber)

subscriber.assertComplete()
```

Comment: thnks Anatolii Chub, its exactly what i need..!!